# How to print new line in textarea in internet explorer while reading from a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, textarea

I have a scenario like this:

I have file (say abc.txt) and i want to read contents from that file and print in a JSP page in a textarea.

But the problem is that the textarea show all contents in one single line without line feed and carriage return.

In mozilla firefox and google chrome it prints in the desired format but in INTERNET EXPLORER  it has got the problem of displaying.

In the text file the contents are like in this format

![image: Required format]

and i want to print the contents in this way in the textarea also.

But it is printing like this:

[image]

I am using this Ajax function to get the textarea contents from the JSP file:

```
 function contentDisp1() {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url : "sql_Execution_Log_Reader.jsp",
            success : function(data) {
                $("#contentArea1").html("<pre>"+data+"</pre>" );
            }
        });
    }
```

and the file sql_Execution_Log_Reader.jsp contains this code :

```
<%
  BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("D:/mout.txt"));
String line = "";
StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer();
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
{
//line = line.replace("/\n(?!\r)/g", "\n\r");
out.println(line);
}
input.close();
%>
```

So how do i write in the Ajax function

Comment: Thanks but i am doing it in java using css,ajax,jquery

Comment: how you setting contents to textarea ? can you show us your code ?

Answer (score 0):

IE (as most microsoft software) use character 0x0D as end of line, not 0x0A. So you need to convert all your line ending to this character.
For example in jQuery this wil work:

```
$('#area').text('First line' + String.fromCharCode(13) +'Second line');
```

Comment: To be completely sure - create a CrLf (10 + 13) so all browsers understand it.

Comment: No, you couldn't use (10 + 13), because in this case most browsers will give two end of lines. Use (13 + 10) if you want full CRLF. But 13 is simplier and I didn't find modern browser which can't understand this.